# GraalVm - Java complex object can't be parsed like javascript object

Tags: javascript, java, graalvm

I am trying to migrate from nashorn to graalvm (java 11). I have a lot of java script.

Description ->  Connecting to java project as maven libs org.graalvm.js: graal-sdk, js, js-scriptengine, org.graalvm.truffle: truffle-api. Version 1.0.0-rc9.
 ScriptEngine created like 'new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("graal.js")';
 Then you can create map in array in map like:

```
Map mapOuter = new HashMap();
Map mapInner = new HashMap();
List arrayInner = new ArrayList();

mapInner.put("1", 3);
arrayInner.add(mapInner);
mapOuter.put("2", arrayInner);
```

Then convert mapOuter to ProxyObject like ProxyObject.fromMap(mapOuter);
Evaluate test javascript with code like:

```
function test(param) {
   &nbsp;&nbsp;print(param["2"]);
   &nbsp;&nbsp;param["2"].forEach(function(inArray){
   &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;print(inArray);
   &nbsp;&nbsp;});
}
```

Which will invoke error like:

> javax.script.ScriptException: org.graalvm.polyglot.PolyglotException: TypeError: INVOKE on foreign object failed due to: Message not supported: INVOKE

**So the question is**: how to make graalvm to transfer complex java object to javascript function properly?

p.s. What i want in this example is to call object like:

> print(param["2"][0]["1"]);

and it prints me 3.
**What i tried:**
tried to parse each member of outerMap as ProxyObject/ProxyArray.
**What was working**
If you change javascript like:

> print(param["2"][0].get("1"));

it will prints 3;

Answer (score 0):

Currently (Dec 2018) using `[]` to access values of a Java Map is not supported.You need to convert maps to a `ProxyObject` to make `[]` work. Like you did with the `mapOuter` object.

Otherwise it's a normal Java map on which you call `.get(key)` to obtain the value.

Comment: I used ProxyObject, but it's not working. I also tried to use [ProxyObject in ProxyArray in ProxyObject] construction but it's not working.

Comment: If I do it like in the following gist it works for me: https://gist.github.com/shelajev/5529229d2913d952529d249251f9abcb. Can you please elaborate the question or provide a better code example?

Comment: Thank you it worked, but there is another problem -> "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Multi threaded access requested by thread Thread[] but is not allowed for language(s) js" such error invoking alsmot every run. Is there a way to solve it?

Comment: **In your example you use ArrayList as is, so  when i try to use javascript array push() method, it causes to error "javax.script.ScriptException: org.graalvm.polyglot.PolyglotException: TypeError: INVOKE on JavaObject (java.util.ArrayList)] failed due to: Unknown identifier: push"**